# Count records by Grouping a period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores **per day** if a user worked or if he was on vacation based on a value.
Example table, `Value = 1 -> WorkDay, Value = 2 -> Vacation`:

```
User    | Day        | Value
--------|------------|-------
user-1  | 2021-01-01 | 1
user-1  | 2021-01-02 | 1
user-1  | 2021-01-03 | 1
user-1  | 2021-01-04 | 1
user-1  | 2021-01-05 | 2
user-1  | 2021-01-06 | 2
...
```

I'll like to convert this table to this (Using the simple example above):

```
User    | Year | Month | WorkDay | Vacation
--------|------|-------|---------|---------
user-1  | 2021 | 01    | 4       | 2
...
```

I tried using group by, subqueries and case, but the whole thing become a mess.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(Day),
    MONTH(DAY),
    User,

    ...

From Table1
Group By YEAR(Day), MONTH(DAY), User
```

Comment: You are on the right track. Just need conditional aggregation. Question well asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select year(day), month(day),
       sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as workday,
       sum(case when value = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as vacation
from table1
group by year(day), month(day)
```

Comment: Sometimes the answer is so simple and here I am overengineering it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation as below:

```
select User,
       year(day), 
       month(day),
       sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as WorkDay,
       sum(case when value = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Vacation
from table1
group by User, year(day), month(day)
```

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table table1([User] varchar(50), Day date, Value int);
 insert into table1 values('user-1'  , '2021-01-01' , 1);
 insert into table1 values('user-1'  , '2021-01-02' , 1);
 insert into table1 values('user-1'  , '2021-01-03' , 1);
 insert into table1 values('user-1'  , '2021-01-04' , 1);
 insert into table1 values('user-1'  , '2021-01-05' , 2);
 insert into table1 values('user-1'  , '2021-01-06' , 2);
```

Query:

```
 select [User] as "user",
        year(day) as "year", 
        month(day) as "month",
        sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as WorkDay,
        sum(case when value = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Vacation
 from table1
 group by [User], year(day), month(day)
 GO
```

Output:

| user | year | month | WorkDay | Vacation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user-1 | 2021 | 1 | 4 | 2 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7871bee50d44f819898bba2dd0d1cf80)*